# Cannot use string offset as an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, fatal-error

Hey guys i have an array that looks like this

```
Array
(
        [0] => Array
                (
                        [Marque] => AUDI
                        [Famille] => A4 Avant N1
                )
        [1] => Array
                (
                        [Marque] => AUDI
                        [Famille] => A3
                )
        [2] => Array
                (
                        [Marque] => AUDI
                        [Famille] => A5
                )
        [3] => Array
                (
                        [Marque] => AUDI
                        [Famille] => A4
                )
)
```

i need an array that looks like this:

Quote

```
Array
(
    [AUDI] => Array
    (
        [0] => A4 Avant N1
        [1] => A3
        [2] => A5
        [3] => A4
    )

)
```

so fare i got this going:

```
if (isset($_GET['debug'])){ $stri=array(); $i=0; foreach($csv_array as $car){
    if ( !in_array("$car[Marque]", $stri) ) {
    $stri[] = "$car[Marque]";
    }
    if ( !in_array("$car[Famille]", $stri) ) {
    $stri[$i][$car[Marque]][] = "$car[Famille]";
    }     $i++; }

echo "<pre>"; print_r($stri); echo "</pre>";
```

but that gives me

Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array

Answer (score 0):

Try putting quotes around your array keys:

```
if (isset($_GET['debug'])){ $stri=array(); $i=0; foreach($csv_array as $car){
    if ( !in_array("$car['Marque']", $stri) ) {
    $stri[] = "$car['Marque']";
    }
    if ( !in_array("$car['Famille']", $stri) ) {
    $stri[$i][$car['Marque']][] = "$car['Famille']";
    }     $i++; }

echo "<pre>"; print_r($stri); echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: "$car['Famille']" is not valide php in any case, thats not solving the fatal error

Comment: i changet to this and get the same problem

[code]if (isset($_GET['debug'])){
$stri=array();
$i=0;
foreach($csv_array as $car){
    if ( !in_array($car['Marque'], $stri) ) {
        $stri[$i] = $car['Marque'];
    }
    if ( !in_array($car['Famille'], $stri) ) {
        $stri[$i][$car['Marque']][] = $car['Famille'];
    }    
$i++;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($stri);
echo "</pre>";[/code]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use single quotes to pull out values correctly:

```
$car[Famille] => $car['Famille']
```

[EDIT] Now I understand...

```
$stri = Array();

foreach($csv_array as $car)
{
    if (!array_key_exists("$car['Marque']", $stri))
    {
        $stri["$car['Marque']"] = Array();
        $stri["$car['Marque']"][] = "$car['Famille']";
    else
        $stri["$car['Marque']"][] = "$car['Famille']";
}

var_dump($stri);
```